# Lost keystore alias but have file and password used for alias

Tags: android, google-play, alias, keystore

recently I added a new alias to my keystore to sign my app.

Now I lost the new generated file with the alias, but remember the password and the alias name and have an older copy the file. Is there a way to recreate the alias using this things?

Comment: you mean new keystone you lost..

Comment: More or less, yes.
If there is no random component in the creation of the alias, i should be able to recreate it.

Comment: @waronin3D So finally did you find the solution?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can list the contents of your keystore with the command:

```
keytool -list -keystore <name of keystore file>
```

To do this, you will need to provide the keystore password (not the alias password). This will tell you the aliases in the file, which are self-contained, allowing you to sign. If you wish, you could also extract keys using other options / tools.

Comment: I know the alias is not in the file.
Now looking for a way to recreate it somehow.

Comment: Not possible. If it were possible, if I knew your alias name then I could fabricate your signing key to impersonate your signature. The password has no bearing on the contents of the alias, only on the extraction of the signing key for that alias within the keystore. To answer your comment above -- there is, and must be, a random component in the generation, for security needs.

Comment: So the alias content is generated random?

Comment: The alias is simply a name to help you locate the key. The key is the magic sauce, which is randomly generated. The alias can be changed without any affect on the key... so yes. Isn't this how you would design a system if security were important? If not, there would be no cryptographic strength to the process.

Comment: Works like a charm, I had the file and the password but required the alias! Thanks!

Comment: Use verbose to extract the full key info `keytool -list -v -keystore <name of keystore file>`.

Answer (score 42):

Open your key store (.jks) file with text editor. It will display binary form of data. The readable text in the first line is your key alias.

For example, `your key alias` in the following binary data is the key alias.

`þíþí    your key alias  UYY_  0‚þ0
+* ‚êa÷í–ØRö}ðÅ¾áä¶ˆùÎL\ô©2‘wå¥H¨V †¸®Àµ£ð×þ7—â;TÁÙcsª”ž˜4ÝÉ'AÀì,’„×S¼ðßÅ'€Õ¡ó‚˜ ö!y’Çåx|(woÁh4u-û†‚‡§QÈ¸|ˆ³”ÜæûZŽ²a±O­´¢^À.ªbÅ“e†6 Éç§®j§˜y ößÿØ0Çd@ /Ã?®¦ìé¼/§Zq””Ê•©„=~Ùì¢>º}DàO<Ö¹SbpÎŒ@Ø„°^Í^e»>¾ü«nM(
"Nbûh·2ðÁ0¯ç¿61êè“[.ÇzeYŽºXkuÄy*ôq¥FSs]:2“ì`

Comment: you are a lifesaver!

Comment: You are a legend!!

Comment: That's Perfect, it's 100% working

Answer (score 10):

http://tim12332013.blogspot.tw/2014/10/corona-sdk-android-keystore-lost-alias.html

look it may help you

`keytool -list  -v -keystore X:/XXXX /XXXX.keystore -storepass XXXX`

Comment: Thanks Man, this is help me

Comment: great answer ! helped me a lot !

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "file address"
```

Copy your alias name and TaDa!!!

Comment: you're a magician  

Answer (score 1):

The default alias in latest android studio version is "key0". You can try this if you haven't changed your alias value.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\YourName\Path\To\my-release-key.keystore" -storepass yourpassword
```

Make sure enclose the entire keystore path within double quotes""