# Android Eclipse key store alias key : is it possible to recover a key?

Tags: android, key, alias, keystore, recover

can anyone clarify me that is it possible to recover keystore alias key?
i am in big trouble my app is already on playstore and update is ready,and stuck at this point

Here is link [bruteforce](https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/)
using from last two days,nothing works for me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost keystore alias but have file and password used for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119714/lost-keystore-alias-but-have-file-and-password-used-for-alias)

Comment: followed the accepted answer from above link,and as i know there is alias, can you guide me to extract  key..i don't know how to do that..and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to comment there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and find the password in one of the gradle files if you still have the source code and were using Android Studio to develop the app. Try looking for:

```
..Project\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin
```

Alternatively, you can create new keystore and set new password for it with the keytool command below. You don't need original keystore password for it:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore path/to/keystore/with/forgotten/pw \
-destkeystore path/to/my/new.keystore
```

When prompted, create password for your new.keystore and for source keystore password (which you lost) just hit Enter.
You will get warning about integrity not checked, and you will get your new.keystore identical to original with newly set password.

The reason this works is keystore password is only used to provide integrity of the keystore, it does not encrypt data with it, in contrast to private key password, which actually keeps your private key encrypted.

Comment: right now i am using Eclipse to develop app so first solution is not solution for me,let me try second one..

Comment: its saying keytool error : java.security.unrecoverableKeyException : can not recover key. it asked for destination keystore pass and than reEnter it than source keystore pass and then key pass for source key which is same as backed up,